# How to fix "error: unknown command "join" for "kubectl""

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Im trying to join a worker node to a Kubernetes cluster using the kubectl join command.
Attempted to fix the issue by running the command below.

*To fix this issue, you need to update the kubectl command-line tool to match the version of the Kubernetes cluster.*

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/arm64/kubectl"
```

*Once you have downloaded the latest version of kubectl, you need to make it executable and move it to a location in your PATH:*

```
chmod +x kubectl
sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

New suggested method below command didn't work either.

```
sudo snap install kubectl --classic
```

*To view the current version of Kubernetes installed on your system, you can use the kubectl version command.*

```
ubuntu@master:~$ sudo kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.4+k3s1", GitCommit:"8d0255af07e95b841952563253d27b0d10bd72f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-20T00:33:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.4+k3s1", GitCommit:"8d0255af07e95b841952563253d27b0d10bd72f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-20T00:33:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}

*To view the current version of kubectl, you can use the kubectl version command.*

ubuntu@master:~$ **sudo kubectl version --client**
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.4+k3s1", GitCommit:"8d0255af07e95b841952563253d27b0d10bd72f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-20T00:33:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7

ubuntu@worker:~$ **kubectl version --client**
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.1", GitCommit:"4c9411232e10168d7b050c49a1b59f6df9d7ea4b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-14T13:21:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1

# Linux master 6.2.0-1004-raspi #5-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 10:50:45 UTC 2023 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
# Linux worker 6.2.0-1004-raspi #5-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 11:15:14 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re running the wrong command; to join a node to a cluster, you need to use [`kubeadm join`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/). Note `kubeadm`, not `kubectl`.

Comment: ubuntu@worker3:~$ sudo kubeadm join 192.168.1.158:6443

[discovery.bootstrapToken.caCertHashes: Invalid value: "": using token-based discovery without caCertHashes can be unsafe. Set unsafeSkipCAVerification as true in your kubeadm config file or pass --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification flag to continue, discovery.bootstrapToken.token: Invalid value: "": the bootstrap token is invalid, discovery.tlsBootstrapToken: Invalid value: "": the bootstrap token is invalid]
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Comment: Have you read the documentation linked from the answer? You need to provide a discovery token or configuration file. In any case, your question was about not being able to run `kubectl join`; given your comment, I take it my answer worked for you and you were able to run `kubeadm join`, even if it didn’t complete successfully. If you have further issues, please ask new questions, that way you’ll have room to provide details.